# MaxScript to collect all VRay materials in the scene

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

Hello this is my first script ever. 
I am trying to write a script that will get all VRay materials in the scene into an array, after that I want to pull them trough for loop and attach each vray material to a slot in Multi/Sub-Object. And then output of multi/sub object connect to VRayMtlWrapper and keep the old multisub object as sub material.

I can do that in graph but it takes to long with double digits amount of materials.

I've scraped some scripts and read maxscript help to find what I need but with no luck.

Atm I know to collect materials in the scene

```
materials = for m in scenematerials collect m;
```

but after that i dont know how to write so that i can access their outputs/inputs or attributes and connect them with a multi sub object.
I have developed the logic in my head but dont know how to write the syntax to realise it.
Any info, directions, links would be appreciated.

Here's even an image of what im trying to do with a script automaticaly 
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM1vg.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

I have found a solution.
If you want to pickup only vray u just write:

```
matVray = for m in scenematerials m.category == #vray collect m;
```

If you would like to pickup only materials in vray library, just add

```
matVray = for m in scenematerials m.category == #vray and superclassof m == material collect m
```

For putting materials from array into a multisub object then its:

```
multiSub = Multimaterial numsubs:matVray.count
multiSub.materiallist = matVray
```

And last part connecting multisub to vray wrapper:

```
vrayWrapper = VRayMtlWrapper baseMtl:multiSub
```